# People in theater probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are $200$ seats in a theater, $10$ of which are reserved for the press. $150$ people come to
the show one night, and are seated randomly. What is the probability of all the seats reserved
for the press to be occupied? Can somebody give me some ideas, please? I can't figure out what probabilistic model to use.

Comment: Hypergeometric distribution

Comment: filling up so many of the available seats and without following a pattern, today just sounds ... strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question utilises the hypergeometric probability distribution. We have $N=200$ seats, $n=150$ seats that are occupied on the given night, and $r=10$ seats reserved for the press.

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a discrete random variable representing the number of press seats occupied, where $\mathbb{X}=0,1,...,10$. Thus $\mathbb{X}\sim$ Hyp$(200,150,10).$

We want to know the probability when *all* of the press seats of occupied, $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{X}=10)=p(10)$.

Using the formula for the hypergeometric distribution, we obtain $p(10)=\frac{{10\choose10 }\cdot{190\choose140}}{200\choose150}=0.0521$.